# Is there any common way to save application settings in more advanced way, than plain .settings file?

Tags: c#, wpf

There's a large WPF application with several modules, windows, self-written controls, etc.
We need to persist state for some of elements of user interface. For example:

- windows layout;
- controls layout;
- last accepted input;
- various grids' state(columns' visibility, width, order)

.Settings file seems too plain for this because of no hierarchy in it.
Why can't I just serialize some `SettingsModel`, containing everything I need and then restore it on application startup?
The very important requirement for persistence mechanism is that it shoud be **extensible**: If I refactor settings structure, and will try to de-serialize the file created with some previous version of `SettingsModel` class, I will obviously fail.

So the quiestion is: are there any frameworks for persisting complex settings?

Comment: Why not store the data in an XML file?

Comment: Rachel, and then what? Write a 200 lines parser? write one more after each refactoring?

Comment: I don't usually work with XML (I use a database), however I'm fairly sure there are some pre-built objects that you can use to easily read/write data in XML files. You shouldn't have to write a parser, although you will probably need to write something that maps the XML data to/from your object

Comment: @IlyaSmagin: The XmlSerializer does most things automatically using reflection. For most purposes you need to do absolutely nothing.

Comment: Guys, I know what serialization is. The questions is extensibility and support for not-yet-updated serialized file :|

Comment: That's what the XML is for... you store raw data there and then map it to your data model. If your data model has been updated and a new field doesn't exist in the XML file, use a default value.

Comment: @IlyaSmagin XML has a great deal of support easily available, if you name things well so things don't need to be renamed over time defaults can easily be given to new fields. At worst, you recognize that you're getting an old format and refresh it to your latest if you do need to change names. What other format is going to be easier to handle upgrading data than XML?

Comment: @ThatChuckGuy, ok, XML it is. But it is just storage, how will all the dirty job(migrating from old-version settings to new-version) be done? I'm not looking for do_magic(); just trying to understand the flow.

Comment: @IlyaSmagin This SO question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/1201077/1078151) has a couple suggestions. It basically comes down to having multiple readers, having an XSLT, or using a versioning parser. Which fits better depends on your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .Settings file supports [changing the structure over time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.iapplicationsettingsprovider.upgrade.aspx). You don't even need to use the Settings.cs file you can make your own [settings providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingsprovider.aspx) and have them populate from the config file, each with their own customized Upgrade method to handle changes in the structure.

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be the closest to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

As Rachel suggested, you could use [XML serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx), i for one always use that for settings, it has some tolerance for changes but i do not know if it would fit all your needs.

Comment: agreed, if the built-in application settings (Per user/app-wide) don't work for one, XML is probably the next best choice.

Answer (score 1):

app.config is another common storage location.  Config file settings can be accessed easily from the application and you can even build your own custom configSections

Comment: The app.config is intended for application settings - not user specific UI settings.  These values should be stored in a settings file (normally xml) in the user's application directory.  The app.config is usually in the Program Files \ ProgramName directory and cannot be modified due to UAC restrictions on most of the new operating systems.

Comment: never knew or even considered that possibility.  thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this by writing my own serialization code to XML, labeling the elements to match the configuration fields. When I deserialize, I query the XML for each element I want to populate. If I'm deserializing an old version into a new config scheme that has additional elements, the XML query returns null and I instead insert a default value. It lets me handle lists of hierarchical data, I can encrypt any portion of it I need, and I don't version the XML. Although its a bit more work than using XMLSerializer, my config data doesn't change very often so it was worth it.

Since you can have lots of users, you can save each user's XML as a string in a database. [System.Data.Sqlite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki), [RaptorDb](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/316816/RaptorDB-The-Key-Value-Store-V2), and [FileDb](http://www.eztools-software.com/tools/filedb/) work well for this, as does [PersistentDictionary](http://managedesent.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PersistentDictionaryDocumentation).

Yet another alternative is to store your data in dictionaries of dictionaries and use [SharpSerializer](http://www.sharpserializer.com/en/index.html) to save it as XML to either a file or one of the above databases.